# How to protect Javascript changes in client side

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an app using firestore database and I am facing certain security issues. For example, the app adds create and write the date with each form submit and check if the write date is late the user must pay penalty. since the javascript code is visible and can be changed on the client-side, the user can modify the write date and bypass the penalty.

To solve the issue I have two options first I can use the server-side which costs me extra server hardware which I don't want to. the second option is using cloud function which costs much higher than upgrading my server hardware. is there any better option to deal with this issue?

Comment: "Using cloud function which costs much higher" -> Have you looked at the [pricing for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)? There is a generous free tier of 125K invocations/month.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you want to generate data in way that the user cannot interfere with it, then you have to generate it on a computer you control (it doesn't matter if it is traditional hosting or distributed cloud hosting) and not on a computer the user controls.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, for you to have complete control over the system, it needs to be programmed and developed in a way that it won't provide "power" for the user - such as JavaScript.

Using Cloud Functions would be the best option for you, as you mentioned. I would recommend you to take a look at the [Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing). There are so very good options, including a Free one. In case you are just starting a system/application, using the free tier might be the best option for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the documentation for Firebase's [server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security). These rules can be used to validate read and write operations that are made directly from the client, and in many cases can cover a large portion of the security needs of direct-from-client access.

In cases where performing certain check in security rules proves impossible or unfeasible, Cloud Functions are a great second tier.